# Emergency Calling

Tags: android

I am trying to design a system of android, in which emergency call can be placed on the number of my desire. I have an interface for patients, in my interface I have placed a button for emergency call to the doctor, if they start feeling sick then on a single button click, a call be placed to the doctor.

```
public void callDoc(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("myNumber"));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

This is what I have tried so far. Is it possible to test this on localhost? I am not getting the desired result. This is my logcat.

```
04-06 11:07:16.925: W/dalvikvm(1786): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     ... 11 more
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=03325465573 flg=0x10040000 }
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at com.edps.EmergencyActivity.callDoc(EmergencyActivity.java:22)
04-06 11:07:16.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     ... 14 more
04-06 11:07:19.613: I/Process(1786): Sending signal. PID: 1786 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

```
String number = "23454568678";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +number));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Use Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you given the CALL_PHONE permission? If not then add the following persmission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Secondly, parameter to `Uri.parse("myNumber")` should start with "tel:" prefix, so say if the number is 1234 then call to Uri.parse should be `Uri.parse("tel: " + "myNumber")`